# Will apps run on the latest version of IOS if they were developed in an older version of Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, app-store

My Mac only lets met run Xcode 13.2, which is an older version of Xcode.

If I develop an app using this version of Xcode and publish it to the App store, will it be able to run on the latest version of IOS on iPhone (IOS 16 and above)?

Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Yes, but from April 2023 Apple will require all apps submitted to the App Store to be built with Xcode 14 https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

Comment: Just be sure to have removed all deprecations to make sure it can handle more upcoming iOS versions. I think you may be able to use xCode 13.4 on your Mac.

Comment: @PtitXav what are depreciations?

Comment: If you ask that means you don’t have any. Deprecation are objects or method of iOS that are marked deprecated and may not be available in future version of system. So an old program may fail if using a deprecated method that as been removed from iOS frameworks.

Comment: There are apps on the App Store that were written several years ago and haven't been updated in years and most still work under iOS 16. The best way to future-proof an app is to avoid doing anything non-standard. Use APIs only as they were meant to be used. However, Apple is always moving forward and as a developer it's best to keep on current tools. You may want to consider options that allow you to upgrade to the latest version of Xcode.